# Does this web app require a task queue?

Tags: python, architecture, celery

## Background

I have a web app that will create an image from user input.
The image creation *could* take up to a couple seconds.

## Problem

If I let the server thread, that is handling the request/response also generate the image, that is going to tie up a thread for a couple seconds, and possibly bog down my server, affect performance, kill puppies, etc.

## Question

**Should I use a task queue, such as [Celery](http://celeryq.org/), so that the server can hand off the image creation, and go back to handling requests/responses?**  I have no problem letting the user who is creating the image wait, but I dont want it to effect other peoples access to the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to say No - for now.

- A couple of second is not that long.
- You'll anyway have to implement some sort of polling (or comet processing) to feed the image back to the user.
- It will make your system more complex.
- Design the system so adding on a task queue later on is feasible and easy.

So, keep it simple at first and get it working, but Keep in mind that you might add a task queue later.

Implement that task queue when/if you need to scale.

Comment: +1: And... if you're using Apache, it will handle a great deal of buffering and concurrency for you.  Indeed with mod_wsgi, you can have many, many backend processes running concurrently.  Until you benchmark, you can't be sure, but the workload it can handle is often huge.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for saving me N hours worth of work.  The main concern for me was that a couple seconds _was_ that long.. One of my personal goals was to provide a good UI, and I thought the user staring at a blank screen for a couple seconds while the image gets generated, and sent, would be sub par.  If there was a queue, I could at least poll and keep them occupied with a message or something to look at.

Comment: @random_person:   "staring at a blank screen"?  How can an HTML page present a "blank screen"?  How do you do that?  Mostly when I submit a form, I stare at the previous page for a while.  Then the page is replaced kind of suddenly.  Also, many folks do fancy idlers in Javascript to show some action.  But I don't know how to make a "blank screen" in a browser.  Can you explain that?

Comment: @random_person The user doesn't need to stare at a non-responding screen, you can do the request using javascript/ajax, and display a spinning progress bar or the like while you wait

Answer (score 0):

I have an image-generating site as well ([Names4Frames](http://www.Names4Frames.com)) and did things like this via AJAX (and PHP). I haven't had any noticeable slow-downs (or dead puppies), but the site in question doesn't generate huge amounts of traffic either. I am not an expert on threads, and to be honest, I'm not 100% sure what your exact concern is and what technologies you're using...

Basically have one page request the image from another page (Perhaps even located on a different server), and when it's done the second page passes back to the first any relevant information about the image for processing/display purposes. If we're only talking about a few seconds, I can't see that being a real problem, unless you're dealing with MASSIVE amounts of visitors constantly using this image creation service.

Answer (score 0):

rule of thumb: use a queue if tasks could pile up.

In your case, the task could take *up to* 2 seconds, assuming 8hours a day, you could do up to 8*60*60/2 = 14400 images a day without concurrency.  If you get over 7200 requests a day, you have a 50% chance of any one of them overlapping.  There are more sophisticated analysis to show the expected level of overlapping you're likely to get; but it seems safe to say that you could do over a thousand images a day before getting overloaded.

Now the question seems easier: Do you think you'll get more than a thousand or two image creations a day anytime soon?  If so, then set a queue; if not, leave it for later.

In any case, keep good logs; make sure that you could tell when there's any processing overlap.  Remember that once you get two tasks processing concurrently, they'll take longer, increasing probabilities that a third one could arrive before finishing the other two, and a fourth... when you arrive to an invisible threshold, performance will plummet drastically.  Don't lose sleep on this, just don't let it happen before you notice.